# Image downloading is not working. it read directly

Tags: php, image, wordpress, download

Image downloading isn't working. It read directly not downloading.

```
if($_REQUEST['image'] == true){

    $URl = $post->guid; 
    echo $URl;
    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, validated");
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($URl)."\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    var_dump(readfile($URl)); 
    die; 
}
```

Comment: [Variables are case-sensitive](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). Change `$URl` to `$URL` (Notice the Ls?).

Comment: i did but its not working....

Comment: The image downloading is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try this header format,

```
 header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
 header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  
 fpassthru($fp);
```

Comment: Avinash i replace but now also i get an same output reading image directly it not get downloading......

Comment: update content type to "application/octet-stream". Because you cant guarantee that the pop-up box, it all depends on how the client's browswer software wants to do with that paticular mime-type.

Comment: Link the image to a zip file, then it will download.

Comment: Can you help how to link the image to a zip file and download.

Comment: sure, just upload the zip file to your file server: (`wp-content/uploads/yourfile.zip`). The link to the file would be: `<a href="/wp-content/uploads/yourfile.zip">Download this file</a>`.